# Trying to display loop on new line python

Tags: python, newline

I am trying to get the following code to output to a new line each time. However, when I view on the `webpage`, it doesn't output as expected.

I have tried `\n` and `||` in the `code`:

```
 if (form.getvalue("username")=="$username"):
        self.wfile.write("Table: Users \n") 
        self.wfile.write("Username  |   Password\n")
                self.wfile.write("test")
```

Output:

```
Table: Users Username|Password test
```

I don't receive any errors

Comment: Are you using Djanog ?

Comment: Where do you write these lines, what type of file and why do you open it in a browser?

Comment: use <br> instead of \n

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Thanks! that did the trick

Comment: @Backtrack Sorry, didn't mean to add Django

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```py
lines = [
    "Table: Users  ",
    "Username  |   Password",
    "test",
]
self.wfile.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

try it：

```
self.wfile.write("\r\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `<br/>` at the end of the code (inside the quotation marks) worked very well.